# Получение id последнего видео на youtube канале

Tags: python, парсер, discord

Как на python получить id последнего видео с канала на youtube?

Хочу сделать discord бота, который оповещает сервер о новых видео на определённых каналах.
Использую discord.py.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать для этого библиотеку pytube. В примере ниже, можно получить все id, названия и т.д. на канале. Но, если вас интересует именно id последнего видео, то это будет, как раз, первый возвращенный id:

```
from pytube import Channel


def video_id(url):
    return Channel(url).videos[0].video_id


def main()
    print(f'ID последнего видео: {video_id(input("Введите ссылку на канал: "))}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```